# output php variable in a new html tag ,only if conditions are true using innerHTML

Tags: php, html, innerhtml

hi everyone i want to output the value of a (php) variable $email, using inner html ,only if my php if conditions are true.
if people are not leg in they see a.

```
 <a onclick="document.getElementById('fondloginform').style.display='inline'" ><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> (Log-in)(Register)</a>
```

but if my conditions are bigger than 0 (your loged in ) in want that 
t be something like.

```
 <a><?php echo $email ;?></a>
```

this is my code

```
<?php 
       /* Main page with two forms: sign up and log in */
  require 'db.php';
  session_start();
    // Check if user is logged in using the session variable
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in to see this page!";
header("location: error.php");    
}
else {
  // Makes it easier to read
  $email = $_SESSION['email'];
  $active = $_SESSION['active']

 }
 ?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>      
  <?php 
    function myFunction(){
       echo '<script>
   document.getElementById("accountlog").innerHTML = "New text!";
```

"new text"---this is were i want to output my $email variable)(only if i am loged in (active < 0 ) because i have a row in my database named active and only if your loged in and email verify you active number is higher than 0.

```
       </script>';
       }
       if ($active > 0){
       myFunction();
       }
   ?>   
 <header>
    <!-- TOP HEADER -->
        <div id="top-header">
            <div class="container">

                <ul class="header-links pull-right">

                 <li id="accountlog"><a  onclick="document.getElementById('fondloginform').style.display='inline'" ><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> (Log-in)(Register)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /TOP HEADER --><!-- /HEADER -->

</header>
</body>
```

I am using the onlick switching the display to online because wen i am not loged in and we click on (log-in)(signup) it open a log in Form.switching the display propieties so i cannot take this out .

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is this

```
if ($active > 0){
     echo "<script>
           document.getElementById('accountlog').innerHTML = '$email';
            </script>";
}
```

Completely remove `myFunction()` since its not actually needed.
Hope i helped :D

### Update Printing the $email variable only if $active > 0 without javascript

```
<?php $var = ($active > 0) ? $email : '<a  onclick="document.getElementById("fondloginform").style.display="inline""><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> (Log-in)(Register)</a>'; ?> 
<li id="accountlog"><?php echo $var;?></li>
```

### With innerHTML

I think the first method i posted should work fine with the innerHTML if not let me know what the errors are.

Comment: it was working wen i was loged in ( active > 0 ) it was outputing 'new text' in the good place ,it was just that im not able to make it work and outpit a variable or any html tag

Comment: if i understand correctly you want to echo the user's email only if active>0 inside the li element correct?